# from pycontextbroker.cb_attribute import ContextBrokerAttribute ImportError: No module named cb_attribute

Tags: python, pip, importerror, broker

I'm trying to use the Python library for Orion Context Broker named pycontextbroker, I installed it:

```
pip install pycontextbroker
```

Install the requeriments:

```
requests==2.9.1
```

Then try to do that import:

```
from pycontextbroker.pycontextbroker import ContextBrokerClient
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycontextbroker/pycontextbroker.py", line 3, in <module>
from pycontextbroker.cb_attribute import ContextBrokerAttribute
ImportError: No module named cb_attribute
```

Any idea? I really need solve that.

Comment: can you provide the output of pip list?

Comment: Pip list backports.ssl-match-hostname (3.5.0.1)
blivet (1.0.10)
chardet (2.2.1)
coverage (4.0.3)
decorator (3.4.0)
Django (1.9.8)
django-appconf (1.0.2)
django-bootstrap-themes (3.3.6)
django-braces (1.9.0)
django-chartit (0.1)
django-chartit2 (0.2.2)
django-compressor (2.0)
django-highcharts (0.0.1, /home/aneto/Documentos/TCC/Projeto/project/django-highcharts)
django-sb-admin (0.3.6)
gevent (1.1rc3)
greenlet (0.4.9)
gyp (0.1)
iniparse (0.4)
IPy (0.81)
kitchen (1.2.1)
langtable (0.0.34)
matplotlib (1.4.3)
mod-wsgi (4.5.3)
mod-wsgi-httpd (2.4.12.6)

Comment: mysql-connector-python (1.1.6)
MySQL-python (1.2.5)
mysqlclient (1.3.7)
nose (1.3.7)
ntplib (0.3.2)
numpy (1.9.2)
Pillow (2.8.2)
pip (8.1.2)
policycoreutils-default-encoding (0.1)
pwquality (1.2.4)
pycontextbroker (0.2.1)
pycurl (7.19.5.1)
Pygments (1.6)
pygobject (3.16.1)
pygpgme (0.3)
PyIscsi (1.0)
pykickstart (1.99.66)
pyliblzma (0.5.3)
pymongo (3.2)
pyparsing (2.1.5)
pyparted (3.10.7)
PySocks (1.5.6)
python-augeas (0.5.0)
python-dateutil (2.4.2)
python-dmidecode (3.10.13)
python-meh (0.38)
python-systemd (231)
pytz (2012d)

Comment: pyudev (0.16.1)
pyxattr (0.5.3)
rcssmin (1.0.6)
requests (2.10.0)
rjsmin (1.0.12)
rpm-python (4.12.0.1)
seobject (0.1)
sepolicy (1.1)
setroubleshoot (1.1)
setuptools (17.1.1)
simplejson (3.8.2)
six (1.9.0)
slip (0.6.4)
slip.dbus (0.6.1)
SSSDConfig (1.13.4)
urlgrabber (3.10.1)
urllib3 (1.15.1)
virtualenv (15.0.2)
wheel (0.26.0)
yum-metadata-parser (1.1.4)

Answer (score 0):

go to given location "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycontextbroker/" and Open the file "pycontextbroker.py" and replace the code with given import code

```
from cb_attribute import ContextBrokerAttribute
from cb_entity import ContextBrokerEntity
from cb_subscription import ContextBrokerSubscription
```